# Can I upgrade from iPhone 4 w/ iOS7 to iPhone SE and iTunes restore?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

Can I upgrade from iPhone 4 running old iOS7 to iPhone SE running iOS 9 and use iTunes backup restore functionality so that I don't have to reinstall everything?

Comment: What is your computer's OS version?  iOS 9 requires a version of iTunes which does not work with older OSes.

Comment: AFAIK everything is latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can always restore from and older to a newer iOS version, however you can't go from a newer iOS version and restore to an older version.